# Filter using Date in DataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to extract datatable from a datatable - dt, where date is greater than 2 months.

I used the following query:

```
DateVariable => DateTime Variable

dt.AsEnumerable.Where(function(x) DateTime.ParseExact(x(“date”).ToString,“MM/dd/yyyy”,Nothing)<DateVariable)
```

> Error: Option Strict on disallowing late binding.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C#?

Comment: You have a DateTime variable and you are trying to compare it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to compare dates keep both sides of the comparison as a date.

I used the `.Select` method of the `DataTable` to return an array of `DataRow`'s that match the criteria. Then I used the .`CopyToDataTable` method to fill a second `DataTable`.

```vb
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim MyDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'Fill the data table with your data
    Dim drs = dt.Select($"date < {MyDate}")
    Dim dtFiltered = drs.CopyToDataTable
End Sub
```